# SQL select max year/month by separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select rows by max YEAR/MONTH value and made this rather complex query. It works but it cannot be the most performance wise solution?

```
Select Max(hr.HRYear) as HRYear, Max(hr.HRMonth) as HRMonth
From data hr,
  (Select Max(HRYear) as HRYear From data) as atemp
Where hr.HRYear = atemp.HRYear
  and hr.HRMonth = (Select Max(HRMonth) From data Where HRYear=atemp.HRYear)
```

Example rows and expected result is HRYear=2014, HRMonth=10 values. Key values are integer.

```
HRYear(int)  HRMonth(int)  Attr1(varchar)
2013         10            aa0
2013         11            aa3
2013         11            bb5
2013         12            aa2
2013         12            aa2
2014          7            cc1
2014          8            dd2
2014         10            ee3
2014         10            ee2
```

Do you have better idea how to select max year+month combination? I need values to run additional queries.

**I have already accepted** Gordon's TOP1..ORDERBY solution, but one (now deleted) idea was this query. I have few hundreds test rows so benchmarking is near impossible, but once I hit +millions of rows in a production it remains to be seen what is the most efficient one.

```
SELECT fst.HRYear, Max(fst.hrmonth) as HRMonth
FROM   data fst
       JOIN (SELECT Max(HRYear) HRYear FROM data) scd
       ON fst.HRYear = scd.HRYear
GROUP  BY fst.HRYear
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `top` or `top with ties` to get what you want:

```
select top 1 with ties hr.*
from data hr
order by hr.hryear desc, hr.hrmonth desc;
```

You would use `top 1 hr.*` if you wanted the result set to only consist of one row.  For instance, if you only wanted the most recent year and month:

```
select top 1 hr.hryear, hr.hrmonth
from data hr
order by hr.hryear desc, hr.hrmonth desc;
```

Comment: I feel stupid now, of course simple TOP 1..ORDER BY does the trick, what was I thinking earlier. I have never seen with_ties keyword but it was not needed here so I don't need to study it more now. thx.